ros2 zstd compression - why is file ending not aligned to library default
When compressing rosbags (ros2) with the zstandard library, why is the file ending '.zstd' instead of '.zst'? The latter seems to be the default one for the zstandard library and is therefore automatically detected. On the other hand, when trying to decompress with the zstd CLI tool, if refuses to decompress a file with '.zstd' ending unless you provide a desired output file name explicitly. So why has ros2 chosen this file ending?
Thank you so much for your help!

One question per post, please
